# Loading a .properties file with Spring (Java)

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans

I am having an issue with loading a .properties file.

The file is called "businessmessages_en_US.properties" and it is stored in "src/main/resources/config/i18n". I have added "src/main/resources" to the build path and in my spring xml I have created a bean:

```
<bean name="messageResource" id="messageResource"
    class="[package].CustomResourceBundleMessageSourceImpl">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>classpath*:config/i18n/*.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Note that the "basename" property must be a string according to the class**

Yet every time I run my program, the logger shoots a message:

```
01 Jul 2013 09:12:34,267 WARN [package].CustomResourceBundleMessageSourceImpl - ResourceBundle [classpath*:config/i18n/*.properties] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath*:config/i18n/*.properties, locale en_US
```

I need the program to read this file so that the logger can have the correct values. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

and then use it like this:

```
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not completely understanding how to implement this solution or if it's just not working for me. I just added a note in my question that the value needs to be a String, as the class which will be reading it requires that type.